# How PHP validation convert to Laravel validation?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I do the validation process in my php code below with laravel validate?

```
$request->validate([
'city' => '??????????????'
]);

<?php

function exist_city($post_array = ["country" => "US", "city" => "Angels","state" => "uncle"]){
    
    if($post_array['country'] == "US"){
        $database_query_result = [
            ["city" => "mardiv"],
            ["city" => "Angels"],
            ["city" => "sardan"],
        ];
        if(in_array($post_array['city'],$database_query_result)){
           return "its okay city";
        }else{
           return "its wrong city";
        }
    }else{
        if(strlen($post_array['city']) > 2){
            return "its okay city";
        }else{
            return "its wrong city";
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I could explain. I don't have a very good English.

```
$request->validate([
 'country' => 'required|min:2|max:2|exists:country,country_code', 
 'city' => 'required_if:country,US|exists:city,name',
]);
```

For example, if the country code is US in the above code, city is required and is there a name in the database?

checks if there is a name in the database even if the country is not US?

I think I should do as follows? Is there another method?

```
if($request->country == "US"){
    $request->validate([
        'city' => 'required_if:country,US|exists:city,name',
        'state' => 'required_if:country,US|exists:city,name',
    ]);
}else{
    $request->validate([
        'city' => 'required|min:2|max:60|regex:/^(?=\S+(?:\s\S+)+$)[\p{Latin}ŞşÇçÖöÜüıİĞğ\s]{2,60}$/',
        'state' => 'required|min:2|max:60|regex:/^(?=\S+(?:\s\S+)+$)[\p{Latin}ŞşÇçÖöÜüıİĞğ\s]{2,60}$/',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the rules based on condition and then call the validate method on it like this.

```
if($request->country == "US"){
    $rules = [
        'city' => 'required_if:country,US|exists:city,name',
        'state' => 'required_if:country,US|exists:city,name',
    ];
}else{
    $rules = [
        'city' => 'required|min:2|max:60|regex:/^(?=\S+(?:\s\S+)+$)[\p{Latin}ŞşÇçÖöÜüıİĞğ\s]{2,60}$/',
        'state' => 'required|min:2|max:60|regex:/^(?=\S+(?:\s\S+)+$)[\p{Latin}ŞşÇçÖöÜüıİĞğ\s]{2,60}$/',
    ];
}

$request->validate($rules);
```